# If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^2$ has non vanishing derivative then $f(x)=y$ has finitely many solutions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I can prove this claim if the derivative is further assumed continuous, i.e. $f\in C^1$: Assume $f_i(x)=y_i$, $i=1,2$ had infinitely many solutions $t_n\in [a,b]$. By compactness, $t_n$ has a monotone subsequence that converges, WLOG we take the subsequence $p_n$ to be stricty increasing. As $f_i(p_n)=f_i(p_{n+1})$ we obtain $\xi_{i,n}\in [p_n,p_{n+1}]$ with $f'_i(\xi_{i,n})=0$ by the Mean Value Theorem. But if $p_n\to p$ then $\xi_{i,n}\to p$ hence $f'_i(p)=0$ contradicting that $(f'_1,f'_2)\neq (0,0)$. The last argument ($f'_i(p)=0$) doesn't apply if the derivative of $f$ is not assumed continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us compute the derivative of $f_i$ at $p$. It is defined as $\lim_{x \to p} \frac{f_i(x) - f_i(p)}{x - p}$. By assumption on $f$, we know that this limit exists. To compute it, we can take any sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $p$ and look at $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_i(x_n) - f_i(p)}{x_n - p}$.

What if we take $(x_n) = (p_n)$?

Comment: does this assume that $f'$ is continuous?

Comment: All we use is that $f$ is differentiable, since this implies that $f'_i$ exists at $p$. If it exists, we can compute it by taking any sequence converging to $p$ and look at the difference quotient, as mentioned above. The point is that this quotient is $0$ for $x = p_n$ which implies that the limit is $0$, i. e., the derivative vanishes.

Comment: Doesn't seem to use continuity of $f'$. Thanks